# taste or smell like (that of) a lemon

Tags: relative-clauses, prepositional-phrases, reduced-relative-clauses

1. Sour things have a sharp, sometimes unpleasant, taste or smell *like a lemon*.
2. Sour things have a sharp, sometimes unpleasant, taste or smell *like that of a lemon*. ("that"= the taste or smell)

Are they both correct? Could they be interpreted like this?

a) Sour things have a sharp, sometimes unpleasant, taste or smell **which is** *like a lemon*. ("which" refers back to "taste or smell")

b) Sour things have a sharp, sometimes unpleasant, taste or smell **which is** *like that of a lemon*.

Comment: *Like a Lemon* can be reduced to *Lemony*.   *Sour things have a sharp, sometimes unpleasant, lemony taste or smell.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they are both technically correct, but different.

Example 1 gives "a lemon" as an example of the **things** that have a sour taste.

Example 2 gives "the taste of a lemon" as something to liken the **taste** of other sour things to.

In other words, the word "that" in the second example points to the taste (or smell), whereas without that addition it reads that the lemon is one of the 'things' mentioned at the beginning of the sentence.